# Delphi XE6 Data Explorer - Error while creating SQLite table - Unknown Data Type

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

When I try to create new table in Delphi XE6 data explorer (sqlite), after hitting save button, I am getting "Unknown Data Type" error... I wonder if anybody has that error too, and if there is a fix for that?

[image: Like this]

Searched google for answers, but no luck.

Comment: Some code would help, like what data types are in this here new table...

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Sorry added screenshot...